# How can I convert ColA of a numeric dataframe to sorted by each cell value by removing the duplicates by cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below

| Col_A |
| --- |
| 5544412 |
| 564256 |
| 34342 |

And I am looking for output like:

| Col_A | Col_B |
| --- | --- |
| 5544412 | 1245 |
| 5642356 | 23456 |
| 34342 | 234 |

Comment: For the first row, the output should probably be 1245, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert each row as a string then as a set, sort the values and join each digit. Finally convert the new string as a number:

```
df['Col_B'] = df['Col_A'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted(set(str(x))))).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     Col_A  Col_B
0  5544412   1245
1   564256   2456
2    34342    234
```